# Overriding the create method of Django Rest Framework Serialization

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a `Django` backend where I am using `Django Rest Framework` for building `REST API`.

I have nested serialization, and when I try to serialize the data I have to override the create function of the ModelSerializers. I'm a bit scared that this is going to cause a problem or a loophole in the backend's security as I am not using the default validation when creating an object.

So is it normal to do so?

```
# THIS IS MY MODELS.PY

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UnivStudent(models.Model):
    """
    A class based model for storing the records of a university student
    Note: A OneToOne relation is established for each student with User model.
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    subject_major = models.CharField(name="subject_major", max_length=60)
```

```
# THIS IS MY SERIALIZERS.PY 

from rest_framework import serializers, status
from models import *


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')


class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A student serializer to return the student details
    """
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UnivStudent
        fields = ('user', 'subject_major',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Overriding the default create method of the Model serializer.
        :param validated_data: data containing all the details of student
        :return: returns a successfully created student record
        """
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)
        student, created = UnivStudent.objects.update_or_create(user=user,
                            subject_major=validated_data.pop('subject_major'))
        return student
```

and finally,

```
# THIS IS MY VIEWS.PY


from serializers import *
from models import *
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class StudentRecordView(APIView):
    """
    A class based view for creating and fetching student records
    """
    def get(self, format=None):
        """
        Get all the student records
        :param format: Format of the student records to return to
        :return: Returns a list of student records
        """
        students = UnivStudent.objects.all()
        serializer = StudentSerializer(students, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        """
        Create a student record
        :param format: Format of the student records to return to
        :param request: Request object for creating student
        :return: Returns a student record
        """
        serializer = StudentSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
            serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.error_messages,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make changes as following: they are same as in original framework.

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')


class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A student serializer to return the student details
    """
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UnivStudent
        fields = ('user', 'subject_major',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Overriding the default create method of the Model serializer.
        :param validated_data: data containing all the details of student
        :return: returns a successfully created student record
        """
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        original_user_data = self.initial_data.get('user')
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=original_user_data)
        user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = user_serializer.save()
        # user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)
        validated_data['user'] = user
        return super(StudentSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        # student, created = UnivStudent.objects.update_or_create(user=user,
        #                    subject_major=validated_data.pop('subject_major'))
        # return student
```

and View

```py
class StudentRecordView(APIView):
    """
    A class based view for creating and fetching student records
    """
    def get(self, format=None):
        """
        Get all the student records
        :param format: Format of the student records to return to
        :return: Returns a list of student records
        """
        students = UnivStudent.objects.all()
        serializer = StudentSerializer(students, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        """
        Create a student record
        :param format: Format of the student records to return to
        :param request: Request object for creating student
        :return: Returns a student record
        """
        serializer = StudentSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save() 
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a bad way, you should refer [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) and [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to re-structure your serializer again. I'm sure that you can solve the nested serializer issue in Serializer, no need for custom in View.